# Xaml Textbox focus hiding in UWP 10

Tags: uwp-xaml

Textbox is always focused I don't know from where it is getting focus. Once I navigate from page, then textbox focus is set. I want it to be unfocused.

Thank you,
-Jitendra Jadav.

Comment: Try setting its FocusState to UnFocused or shift the focus to some other control.

Comment: I had tried this but unfocused is not working throwing error,

Answer (score 0):

fixed problem using `FocusManager.TryMoveFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Previous);`

and added dummy textbox control set height = 0 width = 0 and opacity = 0